# In Power Bi, how do I show a second value label in a stacked column chart?

Tags: powerbi, stacked-chart

[image: In this chart, I'd like to add a 2nd label (donors) for each value. see the red arrow]

[image: This is the data table. I'm charting Donations and need the value of Donations and Donors to show on the chart.]

I've only been able to accomplish this with a tooltip, but I need to paste the final viz into PowerPoint, so hovering is not an option for the audience.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with native visuals. There may possibly be a way with calculation groups and custom format strings but it would be a hack. If you want more control over your visualisations, I can recommend Deneb.